# How old would a Macbook Pro need to be in order to have a non-64bit Intel processor?

Tags: startup, 64-bit, processor, 32-bit

My friend has a MBP that was bought 2 or 3 years ago, and I need to help him prepare some software to run. What are the chances he won't be able to boot from a 64bit Linux live USB flash drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was bought new, it's extremely unlikely that it's not 64-bit. Only the very first "February 2006" MacBook Pro 1,1 and 1,2 revisions had 32-bit Core Duo CPUs - all others have been 64-bit. There's a nice summary of models on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend he check rather than assume based on age. Here are directions on How to tell if your Intel-based Mac has a 32-bit or 64-bit processor

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3696

Comment: Agreed, and your link is spot on. I wasn't quite sure if the owner was running OS X though, hence pointing him to the model summary at Wikipedia.